# Is it possible to programmatically capture funds on an order / change order status?

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way utilizing the bigcommerce api to capture funds for a particular order, and then update the status of an order?

I want to integrate bigcommerce with my main ERP system and want to automate the capturing of the funds.

The API doesn't seem to support this, but has anyone tried to automate the store dashboard with something like casper / jasper?

Answer (score 1):

I've done Selenium automation on BigCommerce before *(surprise, surprise, mwah hah...jk:)*. It's been over a year, but here's an example of so while using a headless Firefox browser (this requires some prior installation):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Load Dependencies:
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Config Display and Select Web Driver:
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

#driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Perform DashBoard Login: (replace USERNAME & PASSWORD appropriately) ...
driver.get('https://login.bigcommerce.com/login')
driver.find_element_by_id('user_email').send_keys("USERNAME")
driver.find_element_by_id('user_password').send_keys("PASSWORD")
driver.find_element_by_name('commit').click()
time.sleep(6)

# Now you are logged into the Control Panel. 
# Navigate to the View Orders Page...
driver.get('https://STORE-HASH.mybigcommerce.com/admin/index.php?ToDo=viewOrders')
time.sleep(3)

# Now on the View Orders page, do your logic below. Click the buttons you need to click, etc. 
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='SomeLabel']").click()
driver.quit()
```

I don't recommend this method though. I quite often find myself adjusting checkout flows for many different platforms due to an increase in fraudulent orders, where payments need to be authorized first until they are determined safe for capture.

The way we do this is by integrating directly with the payment processor via an externally hosted application, that is responsible for performing the `Capture` or `Void` and adjusting the order status appropriately. You might alert this application of a new order via a BC webhook or JS trigger placed on the Order Success page.

Answer (score 0):

You could automate with something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), but I am not aware of anyone that has done so in my two years working at BigCommerce. We are looking at ways to enable the API to support something of this nature.